# Using timeouts in a sequence of asyncio tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Would like to have a timeout embedded in each task and an overall timeout for a sequence of these tasks.

[EDIT] Code is simplified based on @Barak's input

```
import asyncio
from random import uniform, seed
seed(1234)

async def fast(n):
    s = uniform(1.5, 1.9)
    print(f'fast work {n} starts and sleeps for {s} seconds')
    await asyncio.sleep(s)
    r = f'fast work {n} is completed!'
    print(r)
    return r

async def slow(n):
    print(f'slow operation {n} starts and sleeps for 3 seconds')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    r = f'slow operation {n} is finished'
    r = print(r)
    return r

async def maketasks():
        # collect the tasks
        tasks = []
        tasks.append([asyncio.create_task(fast(i)) for i in range(3)])
        await slow(4) # this should immediately start!
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(fast(4)))

        return asyncio.gather(*tasks) # returns awaitables

async def dotasks(tasks, timeout):
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(tasks, timeout=timeout)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        e_msg = f'Timed out after waiting {timeout} seconds in wait_for_complete'
        print(e_msg)
        return tasks, e_msg
    return tasks

if __name__ == "__main__":

    result = asyncio.run(dotasks(maketasks(), timeout=2))
    print(result)
```

[EXPECTED OUTPUT]

1. For timeout < 3, I expected result to provide me a list of strings generated by `fast` and `slow` function as result().done() in tasks. Instead am getting a `coroutine` object as shown below ...

```
...
fast work 0 is completed!
Timed out after waiting 2 seconds in wait_for_complete
(<coroutine object maketasks at 0x05AA4568>, 'Timed out after waiting 2 seconds in wait_for_complete')
```

2. For timeout > 3, the program fails with a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error, for:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    result = asyncio.run(dotasks(maketasks(), timeout=4))
    print(result)
```

...though it prints out the messages and completes all the tasks, including fast(4)

1. Appreciate knowing where am I going wrong?
2. What should I do to get the result as a list of strings from the `slow` and `fast` functions, respecting the timeout provided in `dotasks()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a gather task, that task will not complete until all the tasks inside it has completed. I'm not sure what does it mean to iterate it as you do in the for loop.

You can probably extract results from individual tasks by checking their status after you finished waiting on the gather:

```
async def wait_for_complete(*tasks, timeout=2):
    # This code assumes that the inputs are tasks, not coroutines!
    combined = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    try:
       await asyncio.wait_for(combined, timeout=timeout)
       return [t.result() for t in tasks]
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return [t.result() if t.done() else 'Timeout'
                for t in tasks]
```

Comment: I don't think this code will work as written. `gather` returns results, not futures.

Comment: @user4815162342 - that's incorrect, gather does return an awaitable. Please see the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather

Comment: I meant the return value after awaiting, but now I see that you don't actually use that, so my comment is incorrect after all.

Comment: @Barak - tried your suggestion and edited the question. Could you kindly help with the code correction?

Comment: Well, you haven't posted what were the results, so there's not much I can help aside from guessing. My guesses are: 1. In `maketasks`, the `await slow` has literally no effect (you are not adding it as a task, you just delay the rest of the function). 2. **The `r = print...` is meaningless (since print has no return value)** and this is probably why you don't get an array of strings.